# opevcv - VideoWriter - How append new Images after release VideoWriter?

Tags: c++, opencv, video

After save the video at first time, the application need add more frames. But, if the video file exist, VideoWriter object overwrite the existing video. I use the code below to write the video (its a function call):

```
videoWriter  = VideoWriter(videoFileName, CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3'), 30, frameSize, true);
videoWriter.write(matObject);
videoWriter.release();
```

How to continue appending more frames whithout overwrite existing video?

Comment: what ? you just can't. once you release it, that's the end of the movie, write a series of clips, and concatenate them in a different process, later.

Comment: @berak : tks for your comment. I´m using a application with several threads and each one write a video file. If I don´t release the application crash in the end.

Answer (score 3):

**It's just not possible.**

The problem is that the constructor of [`VideoWriter`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter-videowriter) and `open()` will create an empty file at the destination every time.